# Python - Como exibir tabela como "display" no Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, display, print

Como devo fazer para exibir a tabela formatada como o comando "display" que o Jupyter tem (que fica com uma exibição de tabela mais organizada) no Pycharm?

como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A visualização de DataFrame é possível em ferramentas que trabalham com notebooks, no Pycharm apenas para visualização de um notebook já criado.

Existe outra ferramenta da JetBrains com funções similares ao Jupyter que realizam a trabalham com notebooks.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).